# Psuedo After element not showing

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Trying to display a little chevron as an psuedo after element but I can't get it to display for some reason.  I've tried playing the z-index but that doesn't do anything for the image one way or another.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?  This is essentially what I want it to look like:
[image]

```
          <div class="post-arrow post-arrow--left"></div>
         
          <div class="post-arrow post-arrow--right"></div>
      

.post-arrow {
    position: relative;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba($color-black, .9);

    &--right {
        &::after {
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            z-index: 1;
            background-image: url('../../../lib/images/chevron-right.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            content: "";
            color: $color-white;
            height: 80px;
            width: 80px;
           
        }
    }
        &--left {
            &::after {
                position: absolute;
                display: block;
                z-index: 1;
                background-image: url('../../../lib/images/chevron-left.png');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                content: "";
                color: $color-white;
                height: 80px;
                width: 80px;
               
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like your fundamental CSS is ok. I boiled your code down to more simplistic CSS, with no dynamic colors or locally references images and it seems to work ok. I'd check your image paths or something else.

```css
.post-arrow {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  display:block;
}

.post-arrow--right::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-image: url('https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/566/566012.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  content: "";
  color: #fff;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-arrow post-arrow--right"></div>
```

Comment: Ah yes, went up one too many folders in my relative path.  Thanks!